# how to Intent to particular location in google maps with marker on it?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, maps

I'm creating a tour app with Firebase as a backend. I need to know how to intent aparticular location with marker on it?

`Intent i = new Intent (Intent.ACION_VIEW)` like this, or is there any other method to do with marker on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sample for launching google maps with specific Lat & Lng

```
public void gotToLocation(String markerName,Float latitude, Float longitude ) {
    String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q=%f,%f(%s)", latitude,longitude,markerName);
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));;
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
}
```

then call it like this

```
gotToLocation("MyLocation",34.99,-106.61);
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I'll try this one and tell you

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use google documentation.
[Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents)

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=-33.8666,151.1957(Google+Sydney)");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Above example displays a label at the location of Google's Sydney office

Comment: Thanks bro I'll try this one and tell you